# Create schemaless collection in mongoDB via mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schemaless

I have the following mongoose schema records:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('lM', {
    any     :   mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
},'mlr');
```

And in my code I am doing as such:

```
var lm      = require('../server/models/records');

new lm().save(lmr);
```

Being that lmr is a JSON object.

This produces a mongodb database with the name I provided but the records inside that collection contain only:

```
_id: objectID
_v: 0
```

The JSON objects is nowhere to be seen. How can I get the JSON object inside the any wrapper in the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var lm      = require('../server/models/records');

new lm({'any':lmr}).save();
```

In save() method pass callback function[optional] if you want to track error if any.

```
new lm({'any':lmr}).save(function(err){
   if(err) {
      console.log(err) 
   }else{
      console.log('saved')
   }
});
```

To create the schemaless collection you will have to set **strict:false** which is by default true. **strict** option ensures values passed to your model constructor that were not specified in schema do not get saved to the db.

strict option [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)